# (CSS newbie)Textbox disappeared and images got messy

Tags: html, css, image, syntax, textbox

I'm just learning to make a webpage with super basic CSS that's supposed to look like this:
[I put the class name in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwMwT.png)

But when I typed the code, which is this:

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<html>
<head>
<title>2do parcial PROYECTO</title>
<style>
h1{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:violet;
    border-width: 2px;
}
p.cul{
  text-align:  center;
  font-family:  Aharoni;
  font-size:  35px;
  background-color:violet;
  border-style:  dotted;
  border-width:  2px;
  width:  1050px;
}
div{
  float:left;
  background-color:  lightcyan;
   width:  200px;
   border:  15px solid red;
   padding:  25px;
   margin:  15px;
}
img{
   float:middle;
}
div.one{
  float:right;
  background-color:  lightcyan;
   width:  330px;
   border:  15px solid red;
   padding:  25px;
   margin:  15px;
}
p{
float:left;
   background-color:lightcyan;
   width:782px;
   
}
img.one{
  float:right;
  
}
p.dep{
   text-align:center;
   font-family:Aharoni;
   font-size:35px;
   width:1050px;
   background-color:violet;
   border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
}
div.cuadrote{
  float:left;
  position:  absolute;
  right: %100;
  bottom:  800px;
  background-color:  lightcyan;
   width:  200px;
   border:  15px solid red;
   padding:  25px;
   margin:  15px;
}
 img.batorojo{
   position:  absolute;
   right:570px;
   bottom: -394px;
}
   
}
div.cuadrito{
  vertical-align:middle;
   background-color:  lightcyan;
   border:  15px solid red;
   padding:  25px;
   margin:  15px;
}
img.caribe{
  float:right;
  position:  absolute;
  right:35px;
  bottom:-360px;
}
p.blueboxie{
  background-color:lightcyan;
  float:left;
  width: 1000px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Evaluacion 2</h1>
<p class="cul">Eventos culturales</p>
<div>&#161;NUEVOS CURSOS CULTURALES EN CEART DISPONIBLES&#33;Se cuentan con clases de:
*Artes plasticas(Lunes,miercoles y viernes de 5:00 a 6:30pm)
*Ballet(Lunes,miercoles y viernes de 7:30 a 9:00pm)
*Violin(Martes y jueves de 9:00 a 11:00am)</div>
<img src="http://mexicali.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Centro-Estatal-de-las-Artes.jpg" alt="x" width=300 height=200>
<div class="one">Se anuncian proximamente funciones de teatrales de obras de shakespeare en el teatro del estado, 
entre ellas se encuentran desde clasicos como Hamlet o Romeo y Julieta hasta los escritos mas rec&oacute;nditos del autor ya mencionado.Puedes conseguir entradas en ticketmaster.com o comprarlas en la taquilla del teatro a partir del 10 de abril.Informes o dudas al (686)111-1111</div class="one">
<p>Con un festival artístico-cultural el Instituto Municipal de Arte y Cultura de Mexicali (IMACUM) conmemorará el 42 aniversario luctuoso del legendario compositor y cantante José Alfredo Jiménez.

El evento tendrá lugar en las instalaciones de la Casa de la Cultura de la Juventu (CREA Cultura) este sábado 21 de noviembre, y para ello se han organizado una serie de actividades gratuitas para el goce de los mexicalenses.

A las 7:00 p.m. en la Galería-Vestíbulo se inaugurará la exposición colectiva “Nomás nuestro amor”, en la que participan artistas gráficos, plásticos e ilustradores, entre ellos Gabriela Badilla, Odette Barajas, Gabriela Buenrostro, Luis Felipe Vargas Brownell, Fernando Corona, Aída Corral, Carlos Cortez, Mara Leticia Dorantes, Roberto Figueroa, Gloria Gachuz, Marco Manríquez, Pablo Martínez, Rogelio Pérezcano, Natalia Rojas, Karla Sánchez, y Karina Venegas.

Estos artistas tomaron el nombre de una canción de José Alfredo para de ahí generar su pieza con libertad de creación, lo que el público mexicalense podrá observar una gran variedad de propuestas en cuanto a trabajo, técnica y colorido.</p>
<img class="one" src="http://www.zonalider.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_max_width_auto_height/public/article/image/jose_alfredo_jimenez.jpg?itok=9cZnT7Ir" alt="x" width=250 height=200></img>
<p class="dep">Eventos deportivos</p class="dep">
<div class="cuadrote">&#191;SAB&Iacute;AS QUE&#63;...El juego de béisbol más Largo tuvo lugar en el año 1981,
en las Ligas Menores donde se jugaron 33 entradas. Se enfrentaban Rochester (NY) Red Wings contra Pawtucket (RI) Red Sox. Al entrar en la entrada número 21 el juego seguía empatado 2-2 y fue suspendido. Dos meses después el juego se reasignó 
y en 18 minutos el Pawtucket anotó la carrera del gane.</div>
<img class="batorojo" src="http://allswalls.com/images/boston-red-sox-baseball-mlb-k-wallpaper-1.jpg" alt="x" width=200 height=170></img>
<div class="cuadrito">Respecto al base ball se encuentra proximamente la variedad de juegos de la serie del caribe, incluyendo duelos epicos como el de CUBA vs HAITI , ¡No te los puedes perder!</div>
<img class="caribe" src="" alt="x" width=200 height=170></img>
<p class="blueboxie">&#161;SE LE CHISPOTEO&#33;GUADALAJARA, JALISCO (02/ABR/2017).- El Zorro es de los pocos animales capaces de tropezar con la misma piedra dos veces.

Anoche, Matías Alustiza había tenido una noche de ensueño. Dos goles suyos tenían al Atlas en la pelea en el partido y en el Clausura 2017.

A dos minutos del final el argentino puso la pelota en el manchón penal por segunda vez en el juego. En sus pies tenía la victoria que colocaba a los tapatíos en zona de Liguilla.
Alustiza cobró el penalti que representaba la victoria igual que el penalti que representó en su momento el empate a tres. Un disparo con mucha dosis de humillación al arquero.

Gibrán Lajud adivinó la intención del argentino y no se dejó sobajar una segunda vez. Recostó a su derecha y se quedó con la pelota y con el punto para su equipo.

Sí, Alustiza hizo un “Ponchito” González y el Atlas empató 3-3 un juego que debía y tenía que ganar.</p>
</body></html>
```

Everything looks ok on the top, but the bottom part of the page has a the textbox "cuadrote" missing and the images are reallocated. Also I used the command position (googled it, I don't really know how it works) to fix the images yesterday, but they got messed up again.
[Heres what the bottom part of the page looks like in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClSvn.png)

Pretty pretty please help me its a school project due today

Comment: Please break up your code into the appropriate sections of the Fiddle Creater

Comment: Looks to me like you've managed to delete some important elements from your HTML, namely the closing head tag and start of the <body> tag, which should come before that first <h1> tag.

Comment: add <html lang="es-ES">  to the 2nd line, this is your homework, you really should study more On line 122 take out the closing img tag, you don't do that <img class="batorojo" src="http://allswalls.com/images/boston-red-sox-baseball-mlb-k-wallpaper-1.jpg" alt="x" width=200 height=170></img>↩ and line 124 <img class="caribe" src="" alt="x" width=200 height=170></img class="caribe">↩

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to use the fiddle creater xd, thank you guys for the help i made the changes but the webpage still looks the same , ill keep trying different stuff

Answer (score 0):

Something messy about your code, this may sound unrelated but it may speed up with anyone offering help.

Why are you closing your tags with the class in it?

just to name a few:

```
<p class="dep">...</p class="dep">
<div class="cuadrote">....</div class="cuadrote">
<img class="caribe" src="" alt="x" width=200 height=170></img class="caribe">
```

Use:

```
<p class="dep">...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks i didnt know that